# Custom URL Hack - anybody know how can i find the fields IDs from "User" object?

Tags: button, urlhacking, url

I'm new in custom URL hacking.

I am trying to write a custom URL in a custom button. It is suppose to clone the User record, and while doing so, I want some user fields to be cleared. However, I need help identifying those fields IDs (e.g. Email, Name, etc).

How can i refer these fields when writing the custom URL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to open the edit page (of a User in this case) and use your browser's "Inspect" feature to find the `name` attribute of each field you want to set in the URL. An example is `name_firstName` for "First Name".

Bear in mind that Salesforce makes no guarantees about those names staying the same from version to version or the mechanism continuing to work. Hence the use of the term "hacking".

Answer (score 2):

Go to Setup > customize > user object and select any custom field> in the URL you will get the field Id

[image]

**Note:** This is not available for standard fields.

To use use them your URl would be something like

```
/a0U/e?CF00Ni000000EpsgO={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Ni000000EpsgO_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&00Ni000000EpsgY={!Opportunity.Description}
```

[Reference 1](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/)

[Reference 2](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html)

**Update**

Standard fields are a bit tricky. To get the ID of the fields its best to use chrome. right click on the field in salesforce and click inspect element. This will show you the field name in the code. If the Id you need is opp3 so do it like `&opp3=BensOpp`

Comment: Hi Tushar, Thanks! However, I am actually referring to the standard fields. How do I get the ID for standard fields?

Comment: @slyrehc check my updated answer.